# How to remove class from code and still make it work?

Tags: c++, class

so for school i made code and i used classes, but the teacher said i shouldn't have used classes.
 Is the a way to edit my current code so i would be classless?.
 its a binary search tree that is made with class and i need to remove it.
Information on what to do, what to remove or change would help, no need for you to edit my code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
class BST
{
    private:
        struct tree_node
        {
           tree_node* left;
           tree_node* right;
           int data;
        };


    public:
        BST()
        {
           root = NULL;
           parent = NULL;
        }
        tree_node* root;
        tree_node* parent;

        bool isEmpty() const { return root==NULL; }
        void print_inOrder();
        void inOrder(tree_node*);
        void print_preOrder();
        void preOrder(tree_node*);
        void print_postOrder();
        void postOrder(tree_node*);
        void search(tree_node*,int,tree_node*);
        void insert(int);
        void create(int);
        void remove(int);
};

void BTS::search(tree_node* root,int k,tree_node* parent)
{

    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Element not found"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if (root->data == k)
    {
        if (parent == nullptr)
            cout << "element " << k << " found "; //jeigu ieskomas skaicius medzio virsune

        else cout << "element "<<k<<" found "<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if (k < root->data)
        return searcch(root->left,k, root); // rekursija jeigu reiksme mazesne uz sakny einame i kaire

    return search(root->right,k,root);// rekursija jeigu reiksme mazesne uz sakny einame i desine
}

void BTS::create(int d)
{
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
    tree_node* t = new tree_node;
    tree_node* parent;
    cout<<"enter element"<<endl;
    cin>>t->data;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
    parent = NULL;

    if(isEmpty()) root = t;
    else
    {
        tree_node* current;
        current = root;
        while(current)
        {
            parent = current;
            if(t->data > current->data) current = current->right;
            else current = current->left;
        }

        if(t->data < parent->data)
           parent->left = t;
        else
           parent->right = t;
    }
    }
}

void BTS::remove(int d)
{
    bool found = false;
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cout<<" tree is empty "<<endl;
        return;
    }
    tree_node* curr;
    tree_node* parent;
    curr = root;

    while(curr != NULL)
    {
         if(curr->data == d)
         {
            found = true;
            break;
         }
         else
         {
             parent = curr;
             if(d>curr->data) curr = curr->right;
             else curr = curr->left;
         }
    }
    if(!found)
         {
        cout<<" element not found"<<endl;
        return;
    }


    if((curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL)|| (curr->left != NULL
&& curr->right == NULL))
    {
       if(curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL)
       {
           if(parent->left == curr)
           {
             parent->left = curr->right;
             delete curr;
           }
           else
           {
             parent->right = curr->right;
             delete curr;
           }
       }
       else
       {
          if(parent->left == curr)
           {
             parent->left = curr->left;
             delete curr;
           }
           else
           {
             parent->right = curr->left;
             delete curr;
           }
       }
     return;
    }
         if( curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL)
    {
        if(parent->left == curr) parent->left = NULL;
        else parent->right = NULL;
                 delete curr;
                 return;
    }
    if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
    {
        tree_node* chkr;
        chkr = curr->right;
        if((chkr->left == NULL) && (chkr->right == NULL))
        {
            curr = chkr;
            delete chkr;
            curr->right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if((curr->right)->left != NULL)
            {
                tree_node* lcurr;
                tree_node* lcurrp;
                lcurrp = curr->right;
                lcurr = (curr->right)->left;
                while(lcurr->left != NULL)
                {
                   lcurrp = lcurr;
                   lcurr = lcurr->left;
                }
        curr->data = lcurr->data;
                delete lcurr;
                lcurrp->left = NULL;
           }
           else
           {
               tree_node* tmp;
               tmp = curr->right;
               curr->data = tmp->data;
           curr->right = tmp->right;
               delete tmp;
           }

        }
         return;
    }

}

void BTS::print_inOrder()
{
  inOrder(root);
}

void BTS::inOrder(tree_node* p)// naudojant rekursija atspausdinu medi vidniu apejimu
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        if(p->left) inOrder(p->left);
        cout<<" "<<p->data<<" ";
        if(p->right) inOrder(p->right);
    }
    else return;
}


void BTS::print_preOrder()
{
    preOrder(root);
}

void BTS::preOrder(tree_node* p)// naudojant rekursija atspausdinu medi tiesioginu apejimu
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<<p->data<<" ";
        if(p->left) preOrder(p->left);
        if(p->right) preOrder(p->right);
    }
    else return;
}

void BTS::print_postOrder()
{
    postOrder(root);
}

void BTS::postOrder(tree_node* p) // naudojant rekursija atspausdinu medi atvikstiniu apejiu
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        if(p->left) postOrder(p->left);
        if(p->right) postOrder(p->right);
        cout<<" "<<p->data<<" ";
    }
    else return;
}
void BTS::insert(int d)
{
    tree_node* t = new tree_node;
    tree_node* parent;
    t->data = d;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
    parent = NULL;

    if(isEmpty()) root = t;
    else
    {
        tree_node* current;
        current = root;
        while(current)
        {
            parent = current;
            if(t->data > current->data) current = current->right;
            else current = current->left;
        }

        if(t->data < parent->data)
           parent->left = t;
        else
           parent->right = t;
    }
}

int main()
{
    BTS b;
    int punktas=0,c,d;

       cout<<endl<<endl;
       cout<<" MENU "<<endl;
       cout<<" ----------------------------- "<<endl;
       cout<<" 1) sukurti "<<endl;
       cout<<" 2) tiesioginis elementu spausdinimas "<<endl;
       cout<<" 3) vidinis elementu spausdinimas "<<endl;
       cout<<" 4) atvirkstinis elementu spausdinimas "<<endl;
       cout<<" 5) iterpti nauja elementa "<<endl;
       cout<<" 6) reiksmes trinimas "<<endl;
       cout<<" 7) reiksmes paieska "<<endl;
       cout<<" 0) Iseiti "<<endl;
       cout<<" Iveskite norima punkta"<<endl;
       cin>>punktas;
       int tikrinimas = 1;

       while(punktas!=0)
       {

           if(punktas==1)
           {cout<<"Kiek reiksmiu bus sarase?"<<endl;
                    cin>>c;
                    b.sukurti(c); //panaudojam klases sukurti funckija
                    tikrinimas = 0;
           }
           else if(punktas==2 && tikrinimas == 0)
                    {
                    cout<<" tiesioginis atspausdinimas "<<endl;
                    cout<<" -------------------"<<endl;
                    b.print_tiesioginis();// panaudojam klases tiesioginis atspausdinias funckija
                    }
           else if(punktas==3 && tikrinimas == 0)
                    {
                    cout<<" vidinis atspausdinimas "<<endl;
                    cout<<" -------------------"<<endl;
                    b.print_vidinis();// panaudoja klases funkcija
                    }
           else if(punktas==4 && tikrinimas == 0)
                    {
                    cout<<" atvirkstinis atspausdinimas "<<endl;
                    cout<<" --------------------"<<endl;
                    b.print_atvirkstinis();// panaudoja klases funkcija
                    }
           else if(punktas==5 && tikrinimas == 0)
                    {cout<<"elemento iterpimas"<<endl;
                     cout<<" --------------------"<<endl;
                     cin>>c;
                     b.iterpti(c);// panaudoja klases funkcija
                    }
           else if(punktas==6 && tikrinimas == 0)
                    {
                    cout<<" iveskite elementa kuri norite istrinti "<<endl;
                    cin>>d;
                    b.salinti(d);// panaudoja klases funkcija
                    }
           else if(punktas==7 && tikrinimas == 0)
                    {
                    cout<<"iveskite reiksme kuria norite surasti"<<endl;
                    cin>>c;
                    b.paieska(b.root,c,b.tevas);
                    }
                    else if(punktas<8){cout<<"sukurkyte medi norit atlikti punktus"<<endl;}
         cout<<"iveskite kita punkta"<<endl;
         cin>>punktas;
       }
}
```

Comment: Tevas = parent.
Salinti = remove.
print_**** = diferent types of traversals.
code i main is for printing.
Iterpti = insert a number into tree.
Ieskoti = Search

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Wait. you're using C++ for your project, and your teacher said not to use *classes*? Um.. either your teacher is smoking something, or there is some project mandate you're not divulging.

Comment: You can't. Maybe they meant the "execution" code should all be in `main` and non-member functions. But `tree_node` isn't going to change. Maybe your teacher doesn't realise that `struct` means "class".

Comment: Your teacher told you not to use classes? I hope that's not the case and there's just a misunderstanding. I'd suggest confirming that with your teacher

Comment: she said dont use them since we gonna learn them later.

Comment: To be fair, if the class [sic] hasn't been taught classes yet, that's completely reasonable.

Comment: You wrote this code with classes? Why aren't you able then to write it without classes? Where is your problem? And maybe try to use english specifiers in your example code, so that we can understand it easier

Comment: did this few weeks ago and now iam just lost. first year learning and did this with help of internet also.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Using classes is not mandatory in C++, and there are plenty of problems that can be effectively solved without classes.    The teacher's objective in this homework exercise was clearly something different than seeing if the students could construct classes.   Without knowing the actual question and the teacher's rationale - as distinct from the code that the OP has presented - we can't know that use of classes is necessary or sufficient.   The fact that the OP cannot write an equivalent code without classes is telling.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings sorry, non-native speaker, didn't meant to be rude. Deleted the comment

Comment: @Peter I never said it was necessary, nor did I say it was mandatory. I questioned why one would allow/require C++ code, then specifically *forbade* a most-fundamental feature of the language (not even the standard library and its utility offerings; the actual *language*).

Comment: @WhozCraig Because learning is a process. You don't learn everything in one day, and school assignments generally reflect the level of teaching at that point. I don't think that this is any big secret.

Comment: @WhozCraig Because learning is a process. You don't learn everything in one day, and school assignments generally reflect the level of teaching at that point. I don't think that this is any big secret.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'll keep that in mind, and you're right; it's not a big secret whatsoever.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Like I said, the teaching objective could have been something that obviously didn't require use of classes.   The teacher may well have suspected - based on the current progress of the class - that the OP had simply snaffled code from somewhere online, and submitted it without understanding.   Asking a student for a version that doesn't use classes is a TEST to see if the student had understood the problem, or had simply posted a solution obtained elsewhere and submitted without understanding it.  The teacher would be in a position to know if the request is reasonable.

Comment: fixed it thanks for help and sorry if i annoyed you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making *much* use of classes here.

You've created one `paieskosMedis` called `b`, and put some of the application logic into its data members and member functions.

So just move them into free functions and global variables instead. That's probably what your teacher wants.

For example, this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() { m = 3; }
   void bar() { m = 4; }
private:
   int m;
};

int main()
{
   Foo f;
   f.bar();
}
```

becomes:

```
int m;

void bar() { m = 4; }

int main()
{
   m = 3;
   bar();
}
```

And, hurray, you've probably already solved the task you'll get *next* week.

Note that `tree_node` will still be a class, because `struct` introduces classes, but your teacher may not be aware of that and is thinking of them as some separate "struct" thing. So we'll ignore that.

Comment: Thank you, took some time off then after reading your comment i managed to fix it

Comment: @Pagurklis Great!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help, and sory if i annoyed you.
fixe it by moving member functions into free functions.